# Is it possible to get rid of this seam for a tunnel shot?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv-image-editor

I have tried clearing the seams, scaling the uv map up and down, but it won't go away. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a seamless texture?

Comment: If your texture isn't 'seamless' there will always be a seam.

Comment: It's a procedurally generated texture...is there a way to convert it?

Comment: Add a picture of your node graph if that is how you generated it.

Comment: I just added it. Please advise :)

Comment: If it's a 3D texture just use object or generated co-ordinates.